# Can someone tell me why this filter function doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs

Can someone please explain me why this filter doesn't work?  Clicking the delete button on a "friend card" is supposed to reprint list minus the deleted card.  However, while the alert shows up, the list of cards doesn't change.  What's the deal?

edit: adjusted code as per comment, but it still doesn't change anything
edit2: wait, no, right the first time.  Realized that x.index wouldn't make sense because I have no index property

```
   export default function App() {
  const [friendsState, setFriendsState] = useState(friends);

  function deleteCard(index) {
    alert("Deleting");
    let newFriends = friendsState.filter((x) => {
      return x.id != index;
    });

    setFriendsState(newFriends);
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      {friendsState.map((x, index) => (
        <Card
          name={x.name}
          home={x.home}
          id={index}
          deleteCard={() => deleteCard(index)}
          key={index}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why assume the ID will always be the same as the index? It's certainly not true once you start _deleting_ items.

Comment: That's a fine point, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: try `setFriendsState({ ...newFriends})`

Comment: How is `friends` defined? Do the elements have an `index` defined?

Comment: As the comment above mentions, it would be helpful to provide the data definition/shape for a friend object. My best guess is that the index is not the same as the `id` property on the friend object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, I don't really see a reason you can't just compare the object directly instead of checking properties. Try this instead and see if that works:

```
export default function App() {
  const [friendsState, setFriendsState] = useState(friends);

  function deleteCard(cardToDelete) {
    alert("Deleting");
    let newFriends = friendsState.filter((x) => {
      return x !== cardToDelete;
    });

    setFriendsState(newFriends);
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      {friendsState.map((x, index) => (
        <Card
          name={x.name}
          home={x.home}
          id={index}
          deleteCard={() => deleteCard(x)}
          key={index}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

It's pretty clear that your issue is that the `id` property on the objects do not correspond to the objects' index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your items have an `index` property

```
let newFriends = friendsState.filter((x, i) => {
  return i != index;
});
```

Comment: That was my mistake.  I edited the code too quickly based on someone else's critique without thinking it through the original was written using the id property to fetch the index.